# Should I ask a recommendation letter from a supervisor with whom I had sometimes difficult time working with?

Tags: phd, recommendation-letter

I will be applying for PhD positions in the UK. I have three years of previous research experience, and I worked with four professors who could write me recommendation letters.

I will be applying to many schools, so I would like to ask a recommendation letter from all of the professors.

My other primary advisor came from a different culture, and it was occasionally very difficult to work with him. He was sometimes very upset, and so was I, but things never escalated into anything horrible. He moved away about 1.5 years ago; we departed in good spirit. I have been contact with him after that. It is difficult to guess how he sees things at the moment. I appreciate him in many ways but I don't know if he knows that. I think he is a good person.

Should I ask a recommendation letter from him? Most schools ask for 2-3 recommendation letters, so I would not send it to every place I apply to.

(Academically, my performance is very good. I have received big prizes, have a good publication record, etc.)